# Running concurrent services for old and new camera libraries

Tags: android

I have I suppose a bit of a strange challenge. I have a flashlight app that on some phones work with the older Camera library and some om the newer Camera2 library. I have tried to switch between the 2 in code should the one not function properly. This did not work immediately. You has to close and clear the app from recents before it worked with the new library selection (Camera or Camera2). I then decided then instead of trying this in one service to use 2 services, one for Camera and one for Camera2. My question is would this work ? As both libraries will then try and access the camera concurrently? Or will the 2 take turns when I switch between the 2 ? I have built the 2 services and are still trying to get them to work. It looks like both are initialising correctly with both the old and new libraries but not one of the 2 switches on the led although I know the code works as I use it with my previous implementation. If anyone can give more insight or point me to the right reading material specific to this problem it would be great. I cannot seem to find the right material.

Comment: You have many options this depend on how you code is but you check the android api with `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` if is api 21 or more then you use `Camera2` otherwise you use `Camera`. "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but my problem is with support for both. On some devices supporting both camera for instance works better than camera2 and on other devices vice versa. So I need to give the option to be able to switch, which works but not real time and I would like it to switch realtime. When I switch in one service between camera and camera2 it does not work until the app is restarted and cleared in recents.